# Creating a monthly report in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with the following columns

```
CaseID
DateLogged
CompletionDate
```

I am trying to create a monthly stock report.

I need to identify monthly which cases are New, current and Completed each month
for instance, All cases logged only in August are new cases while all cases completed in august would show completed and all cases logged that are not completed will be current.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #temptable 

-- Create date variables
SET dateformat ymd

DECLARE @datefrom datetime = CONVERT(DATETIME, '2019-04-01 00:00:00', 121)

DECLARE @dateto datetime = (SELECT CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -DAY(GETDATE()), GETDATE()) AS date))

-- Recursive date table creation

;WITH monthserial AS
(
    SELECT @datefrom AS monthdate
    UNION ALL 
    SELET DATEADD(MONTH, 1, monthdate)
    FROM monthserial
    WHERE monthdate < @dateto
)
SELECT MN.* 
INTO #temptable 
FROM monthserial  MN

SELECT * FROM MainTable VW
CROSS JOIN #temptable TBL
WHERE DateLogged <= monthdate) test
```

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Things like sample data, expected results, a question, ... help us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use case-when for your situation:

```
select CaseID,
case
   when not (CompletionDate is null) then 'Completed'
   when DateLogged >= @input then 'New'
   else 'Current'
end
from yourtable
order by DateLogged;
```

EDIT

Since we are interested about the last entry, we can add a where clause, like this:

```
select CaseID,
case
   when not (CompletionDate is null) then 'Completed'
   when DateLogged >= @input then 'New'
   else 'Current'
end
from yourtable
where not exists (
    select 1
    from yourtable inner
    where inner.CaseID = yourtable.CaseID and inner.CompletionDate < yourtable.CompletionDate
)
order by DateLogged;
```

Comment: Thanks, but since it will be on a monthly basis. I want them to show only in the month in which it was completed and New, rather than in all cases.

Comment: @Ade_1 we can filter out all earlier instances of a CaseID except the newest, see my edit.

Comment: Aside: An alternative to `not (CompletionDate is null)` is `CompletionDate is not null`.